# If statements with tuples and removing tuples from list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, if-statement, tuples

I am trying to check a list of tuples for certain types of tuples. I thought the _ operator would work here, but it doesn't work. I guess I could iterate through the list and check by hand, but I feel there is a pythonic way of solving this.
Afterwards, I would like to remove all tuples that have a (1, ) in the first position. A filter would be my try for the removal process.

```
self.bids = [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(3,1),(3,2)] 
if (1,_) in bids or (2,_) in bids or (3,_) in bids:
                possibleModes.remove((1,_))
                return possibleModes
```

Answer (score 3):

`_` is just a regular variable name, not a wild card or operator, although it's by convention used to hold values of no use.

To check if any of the tuples has 1, 2 or 3 as the first item, you can use the `any` function with a generator expression, and to remove all tuples with 1 as the first item, you can use a list comprehension like this:

```
if any(a in (1, 2, 3) for a, _ in self.bids):
    return [(a, b) for a, b in self.bids if a != 1]
```